# Where to put as/wrap functions for Rcpp?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have [an R package](https://github.com/compbiocore/RSeqAn) with some C++ header files (from [SeqAn](http://www.seqan.de/)) in `inst/include`. I now want to write as/wrap functions for the data types in those header files based on the guides in the Rcpp gallery. I placed those functions in a file called `charstring.cpp` in `src`. My problem is that when I do `#include <seqan/sequence.h>` I get this error:

> charstring.cpp:4:10: fatal error: 'seqan/sequence.h' file not found

What am I doing wrong? Is it the include statement? Is it the directory structure? I don't get this issue if I implement the function in a different R package that links to the one with the C++ header files instead.

Comment: There is no `src` folder in the linked repo.... But without more information, I'd guess the issue is that you need to add something like `PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I../inst/include` in `Makevars`. Can you update the repo to include all your code?

Comment: Indeed.  And the _default setup created by `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`_ should already do this for you.  Also note the dedicated vignette on the topic.

Comment: @duckmayr you're right, that was the issue. The changes are in the repo now. Thanks.